# SPARK - Join Large Dataset with Smaller Dataset on Daily Basis

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming

I have a always-growing table with ~43 Million unique rows as of today. I need to join this table with another smaller dataset on daily basis.

My cluster config is

```
Nodes : 3  
Memory : 162 GB in total - 54GB per node  
Total Cores : 24
```

Issue:
1. For Batch jobs - How do I join this large table with a smaller dataset on daily basis ?
2. For Spark Streaming - What is the most optimized way to join these 2 tables in real-time ?

My Ideas :
1. Use broadcast variables for this - the smaller dataset is "small" compared to big table but not "small" enough to fit in memory.
2. Process the data in chunks - I don't know how to do this !

I'm looking for some ideas to achieve my goal in the most efficient way from the available Spark Nodes.
Any suggestions or ideas are welcome here.

Comment: what is your storage for rawdata? if you use dataframe join small dataset will be always broadcasted.

Comment: The data is in Cassandra DB.. Yes I'm using Dataframe on the smaller set. I need to join this DF of smaller set with larger dataset from Cassandra.  I have been using joinWithCassandraTable API on smaller sets till now.. But I'm not sure if this the the optimized solution.